# Tkinter canvas doesn't show entire photo image

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a short script to display a photo in a Tkinter canvas element. I size the canvas element to have the same size as the photo, but when I launch the window, I generally only see a small portion of the image, no matter how much I expand the window.

Also when I print out the size of the image, which I am using to set the size of the canvas, this size says (922, 614) whereas when I record mouse clicks on the canvas, the lower-right hand corner is at something like (500, 300). My code is below. What should I change so that the canvas is the same size as the image and fully shows the image?

```
class AppWindow(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, list_of_files, write_file):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)           
    self.parent = parent
    ...
    self.image = None
    self.canvas = None
    self.index = -1
    self.loadImage()
    self.initUI()
    self.resetCanvas()

def initUI(self):
    self.style = Style()
    self.style.theme_use("default")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    ...
    self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self, width = self.image.width(), height = self.image.height())   

def loadImage(self):
    self.index += 1
    img = cv2.imread(self.list_of_files[self.index])                       
    img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx = IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR, fy = IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR)
    b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
    img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
    im = Image.fromarray(img)
    self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)       

def resetCanvas(self):        
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image)
    self.canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0, height = self.image.height(), width = self.image.width())
```

Here is a screenshot showing a photo and how it is presented in the Tkinter canvas:

[image: screenshot]

Here's what I have tried so far:

- Not resizing the image or changing the resizing amount - this doesn't do anything
- Making the canvas double the size of the image rather than equal to the image, likes so `self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self, width = self.image.width()*2, height = self.image.height()*2)` This does make the canvas larger (I can tell because I have some drawing functions on the canvas), but the image stays the same small size, not showing the entire image
- When I display the cv2 format image with `cv2.imshow()` I see the full image, so it's not `cv2` that is cutting off portions of the image.

---

I realized what I have above is not a complete working example. I've pared the script down, and now running this I still see the same problem:

```
import Tkinter
import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, BOTH
from ttk import Frame, Button, Style
import cv2
import os
import time
import itertools


IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR = .3

class AppWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)           
        self.parent = parent
        self.loadImage()
        self.initUI()

    def loadImage(self):
        img = cv2.imread("w_4131.jpg")            
        img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx = IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR, fy = IMAGE_RESIZE_FACTOR)
        b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
        img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
        im = Image.fromarray(img)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)       

    def initUI(self):
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        print "width and height of image should be ", self.image.width(), self.image.height()
        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self, width = self.image.width(), height = self.image.height())
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image)


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = AppWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: What happens if you `pack` the canvas instead of placing it?

Comment: @Kevin I just tried `self.canvas.pack()` and `self.canvas.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH)` rather than the `.place()` call. The results are the same. How/where would you recommend calling `pack()`?

Comment: self.canvas.configure(height = self.image.height(), width = self.image.width()) in resetCanvas?

Comment: @EricLevieil perhaps I have the ordering wrong, but as no observable effect on its own, before or after `place` or before or after `pack`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you place an image on a canvas at 0,0, that specifies the location of the *center* of the image, not the upper-left corner. The image is all there, it's just that you're only seeing the bottom-right corner.

Add `anchor="nw"` when creating the image for the coordinates to represent the upper-left corner of the image:

```
self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor="nw")
```

As for the canvas not being the same size of the image, I'm not seeing that. The image seems to fit the canvas perfectly.

Comment: However... for those who might come here from Windows (and possibly others), that `0, 0` origin ends up clipping slightly. If you notice such clipping of the top and left side with this, try `2, 2` (`1,1` isn't quite enough). Pretty sure this isn't a new problem either.

Comment: I gave it a try with Ubuntu 18.04... that one works with `1,1` or `2,2`, but enlarging the canvas by >= `1,1` is required if the image is offset by more than `1,1`.

Comment: @MartyMacGyver: the clipping is due to the canvas border. The amount of clipping you're seeing is directly related to the `borderwidth` option.

Comment: @BryanOakley I appreciate the reply - I commented as more of an FYI, but `borderwidth` is `0` by default, and I'm not overriding that anywhere. My same exact test code works differently on Linux and Windows in this regard as described above. TBH I'd think it's a latent defect in `tkinter`, though I see you are The Person when it comes to this tool. The comment thread here isn't suitable for an extended discussion of this, but I'd be happy to chat offline about it (I'd file a bug if this is indeed a bug, but either way it'd be good to understand this better).

Comment: @MartyMacGyver: have you verified the default borderwidth is zero? It may be different on different platforms.

Comment: Directly from the canvas's `config()` output: `'borderwidth': ('borderwidth', 'borderWidth', 'BorderWidth', '0', '0')`